# facebook like button not displayed in firefox

Tags: firefox, javascript, facebook

when I access my site in firefox, the like button did not appear:

[js-projects](http://leungwensen.github.io/js-projects/)

It worked in safari and chrome, only disappeared in firefox. the javascript code of loading like button can be found after the

tag, and the social share buttons can be found after clicking on the red button on the top-right part. google+ and twitter buttons work well right now.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you have,try some css:

```
<fb:like id="facebook-like" href="http://mysite.com/index.php" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

Add this to css,it will work.

```
.fb - like span, .fb - like iframe {
    height: 25px!important;
    width: 150px!important
}
```